# Socket.io handling middleware errors

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have the following code:

```
io.use(function (socket, next) {
    if (socket.auth) // user has already authed
        next(); // success
    next(new Error('not authorized'));
});
```

**Where does the error end up?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ends up as an HTTP error code response to the client.

Comment: Talk about scratching my head heh.

Comment: when using socket.io you do http request/ web socket and they get a response. For exaple, if socket.io in the browser did a http request, in which the server threw an error for, you should get http reponse code of 500 or so in the client for that request. you can see that in the network tab.